# Copy Excel chart to Outlook mail message

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I have email addresses in column A, and a chart object in the same sheet.

For each email address, I want to create a new mail in Outlook and paste the Excel chart into the email body.

The problem with my attempt (below) is that the chart does not get pasted into the mail body. How do I fix this?

This my code:

```
Sub smail()        
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim o As Outlook.Application
    Dim m As Outlook.MailItem
    Set o = New Outlook.Application
    r = 1
    Do While Cells(r, 1) <> ""
        Set m = o.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        m.To = Cells(r, 1)
        m.CC = "xyz@anc.com"
        m.BCC = "abc@xyz.com"
        m.Subject = "Test"
        ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
        Set wEditor = o.ActiveInspector.WordEditor
        'm.Body = Paste
        wEditor.Application.Selection.Paste

        m.Send
        r = r + 1
        Set m = Nothing
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with this line

```
wEditor.Application.Selection.Paste
```

is that nothing is selected, i.e. `.Selection` returns `Nothing`, as long as the message is not visible. To solve this, make it visible before pasting:

```
m.Display
```

That worked for me.

Also, you should always declare all your variables using `Dim`, including `wEditor`:

```
Dim wEditor As Word.Document
```