# Access VBA: working with an existing excel workbook (Run-Time error 9, if file is already open)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm writing a macro in Access that (hopefully) will:

- create an Excel worksheet
- set up and format it based on information in the Access database
- after user input, will feed entered data into an existing Excel master file

Opening the blank sheet etc. is working absolutely fine, but I'm stuck trying to **set the existing master file up as a variable**:

```
Sub XLData_EnterSurvey()

Dim appXL As Excel.Application
Dim wbXLnew, wbXLcore As Excel.Workbook
Dim wsXL As Excel.Worksheet
Dim wbXLname As String

Set appXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
appXL.Visible = True

wbXLname = "G:\[*full reference to file*].xlsm"

IsWBOpen = fnIsWBOpen(wbXLname)
'separate function (Boolean), using 'attempt to open file and lock it' method
'from Microsoft site.

If IsWBOpen = False Then
    Set wbXLcore = appXL.Workbooks.Open(wbXLname, True, False)
    'open file and set as variable.
ElseIf IsWBOpen = True Then
    wbXLcore = appXL.Workbooks("ResultsOverall.xlsm")  'ERROR HERE.
    'file is already open, so just set as variable.
End If

Debug.Print wbXLcore.Name
Debug.Print IsWBOpen

Set appXL = Nothing

End Sub
```

When the file is closed, this works perfectly. However, when it's open I get:

Run-Time error '9':
**Subscript out of range**

I'm only just starting to teach myself VBA (very trial and error!) and nothing else I've seen in answers here / Google quite seems to fit the problem, so I'm a bit lost...

Considering that it **works fine when the file is closed**, I suspect I've just made some silly error in referring to the file - perhaps something to do with the 'createobject' bit and different excel instances??

Any suggestions would be much appreciated! Thanks

---

Thank you @StevenWalker

Here's the working code:

```
Sub XLData_EnterSurvey()

Dim appXL As Excel.Application
Dim wbXLnew As Excel.Workbook, wbXLcore As Excel.Workbook
Dim wsXL As Excel.Worksheet

On Error GoTo Handler
Set appXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
appXL.Visible = True

Dim wbXLname As String
wbXLname = "G:\ [...] .xlsm"

IsWBOpen = fnIsWBOpen(wbXLname)

If IsWBOpen = False Then
    Set wbXLcore = appXL.Workbooks.Open(wbXLname, True, False)
ElseIf IsWBOpen = True Then
    Set wbXLcore = appXL.Workbooks("ResultsOverall.xlsm")
End If

Set appXL = Nothing

'-------------------Error handling------------------
Exit Sub

' For if excel is not yet open.
Handler:
Set appXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Err.Clear
Resume Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Just as a side note:
The line "Dim wbXLnew, wbXLcore As Excel.Workbook" does NOT declare wbXLnew as Excel.Workbook but as Variant. You need to use: "Dim wbXLnew As Excel.Workbook, wbXLcore As Excel.Workbook" instead.

Comment: Ah whoops, thank you - fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I'm on my phone so I can't go in to too much detail or do much with the code but at a glance I think you might need to add an error handler so that if the file is already open, a different line of code is executed.

Add 'On error go to handler' (before creating the excel object) and at the bottom
Of your code add 'handler:'. In the error handler, use get object rather than create object.

You will have to ensure you use exit sub before the error handler or it will run the handler every time you run the code.

You can see an example of what I mean here: [How to insert chart or graph into body of Outlook mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35434772/how-to-insert-chart-or-graph-into-body-of-outlook-mail?noredirect=1#comment58606368_35434772)

Although please note in this example it's the other way round (if error 'getting' outlook, then create it).

Example in link:

Set myOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
Set myMessage = myOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

rest of code here

Exit Sub

'If Outlook is not open, open it

Handler:

Set myOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Err.Clear
Resume Next

End sub

Comment: Thanks Steven, this has removed the Subscript out of range error. Ended up repeating `Set wbXLcore = appXL.Workbooks("ResultsOverall.xlsm")` after the If section (since handler skips over this I think?) - I'm sure there's a much cleaner way of doing this but ah well! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Yes, in fact just finished switching things around a little bit (trying to 'Get' Excel first as in the link you posted was a much better idea!) and all seems to be working well - will post up the fixed code now. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

If you move the `appXL.Workbooks` statement to the debugging window, you will find that the names of the items in that collection are without extension.

So in your case, I'm guessing the line should read:

```
wbXLcore = appXL.Workbooks("ResultsOverall")
```

Comment: hmm unfortunately not, that was one of the things I had tried too and didn't affect the Subscript out of range error - thanks though, would probably have caused another error after fixing this one I guess! :D Changed now.